# Pycharm with Spyder Variable Explorer

Tags: pycharm, spyder

I recently started doing research involving python programming and quickly found that I need a variable explorer. I began using Spyder, however I am accustomed to Pycharm and would much rather continue using that as it allows me to code with a dark theme.

From researching options of how I could incorporate a variable explorer-type interface into Pycharm, I saw that someone said that they edited their script in Pycharm and then had a script automatically update in Spyder, providing them with the best of both worlds.

Could any one of you tell me how to set up an automatically updating script in Spyder that works so that I can use Pycharm as my editor while using Spyder as a tool for the variable explorer?

Finally, I have also attempted to use Pycharm's "variable watcher" functionality however I ran into issues as it did not display the values contained within arrays like Spyder does.

What I really need is the automatically updating script.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to open your file both in PyCharm and Spyder. Then you edit it in PyCharm, save it, move to Spyder (Spyder will reload your file automatically) and finally evaluate it in Spyder to get the output of its Variable Explorer. I don't see any other way of doing it.

Comment: a) Spyder now has a dark theme. b) In PyCharm: When running a script in a builtin python console (Right Click on empty space in source code view → Run File in Python Console), you will have a kind of Variable Explorer in the right half of of the console window